# How to redirect Rest API requests from dev server to localhost using Fiddler

Tags: https, fiddler

I have a dev server serving my rest API which is using **SSL** at `https://api.stg.something.com`

I also have the same API working from localhost at `http://localhost:5000`

Now i want with Fiddler to redirect every api request(POST,GET) to my dev server into localhost for debugging reasons

I added to FiddlerScript's `static function OnBeforeRequest`

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("api.stg.iot.vodafoneinnovus.com")) oSession.host = "localhost:5000";
```

but that not seems to work. When i hit a request from Postman to lets say `https://api.stg.something.com/api/stuff`

i don't get the response and fiddler inspector says

```
fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to localhost (for #6) failed. System.IO.IOException The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

The fiddler trying to establish a Secure connection but localhost refuse it.

**How can i go from https request to http in fiddler?**